# Need to run a MySQL join on 2 Zabbix tables to output IP and NAME based on HOSTID

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, zabbix

I'm having trouble creating the output from two Zabbix tables. I would like to output IP(interafce) and NAME(hosts) using HOSTID.

**interface table**

```
| hostid |       ip     |
|   1    |    1.1.1.1   |
|   2    |    8.8.8.8   |
```

**hosts table**

```
| hostid |        name   
|   1    |    test.server.1  |
|   2    |    test.server.2  |
```

So i would like something like this

```
| hostid |      ip       |      name
|   1    |    1.1.1.1    |  test.server.1  |
|   2    |    8.8.8.8    |  test.server.2  |
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join:

```sql
SELECT
    i.hostid,
    i.ip,
    COALESCE(h.name, 'NA') AS name
FROM interface i
LEFT JOIN hosts h
    ON h.hostid = i.hostid
ORDER BY
    i.hostid;
```